# Table class ".table" without horizontal separators

Tags: html, css

I wish to use the default bootstrap style ".table" for HTML table that I am creating for my webpage as per :

[Bootstrap Link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp)

However, I do not wish to add the horizontal separators, plus I also want the columns to be a little closer than they appear currently. Is there any CSS styling that I should use for this?

Basically, I wish to create an HTML table that has uniform column width, height and have some space between 2 rows for easy readability.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add some css in your style :-

Remove  horizontal separators :-

```
table td {
    border-top: none !important;
}
```

and add table-condensed class for columns to be a little closer.

It may help you.

Comment: Perfect, that works. Also, how do I make sure my cell values are perfectly aligned other than adding &nbsp;? Is there any way I can give them all a uniform cell width and height?

Comment: you can add align center in td tag, and please do vote up if its helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to override the table class, you need to create another class named `borderless`.

html:

```
<table class='table borderless'>
```

CSS :

```
.borderless tbody tr td, .borderless tbody tr th, .borderless thead tr th {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: @ user5163359 With twitter bootstrap 3 use: `class="col-md-*"`  where * is a number of columns of width

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for [Bootstrap Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Fiddle example: http://www.bootply.com/vZRIDaqaRm